# Oracle SQL weird issue with my below query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a view name RULE_READOUT_VIEW which has varchar columns named 'READOUTTYPE' and 'CUSTOMERNUMBER'.

When I run the following count query I get only one row as output.

```
SELECT count(1) FROM RULE_READOUT_VIEW
WHERE READOUTTYPE = '5' AND CUSTOMERNUMBER = 'NSMPF';
```

However if run this other query I get a different result and this time count is 11 rows which is what is the expected result.

```
SELECT count(1) FROM RULE_READOUT_VIEW
WHERE to_char(READOUTTYPE) = '5' AND CUSTOMERNUMBER = 'NSMPF';
```

I am not sure why the first query is not working where as only if I force a to_char on the column I get the correct answer. I searched for answers but cannot find any thing satisfactory. Can some one please explain why this behaviour?

I ran the below query to check the length of each and every row too

```
SELECT READOUTTYPE, TO_CHAR(READOUTTYPE), LENGTH(READOUTTYPE), LENGTHB(READOUTTYPE) FROM teoss.RULE_READOUT_VIEW WHERE to_char(READOUTTYPE) = '5' and CUSTOMERNUMBER = 'NSMPF';
```

I got 11 rows as output and all of the columns have length 1.

```
5 5 1 1
5 5 1 1
5 5 1 1
5 5 1 1
5 5 1 1
5 5 1 1
5 5 1 1
5 5 1 1
5 5 1 1
5 5 1 1
5 5 1 1
```

So the columns do no have any addtional whitespaces as well.

View DDL:

```
SELECT --ro.creation_date,
ro.POINT_OF_TIME_DAY                      AS pointOfReadoutDay,
ro.POINT_OF_TIME_HOUR                     AS pointOfReadoutHour,
ro.POINT_OF_TIME_MINUTE                   AS pointOfReadoutMinute,
rot.NAME                                  AS readoutType,
cp.IDENTIFICATION                         AS customerNumber,
mp.METER_POINT_NUMBER                     AS meterPointNumber,
ro.ORDER_REFERENCE                        AS readoutOrderNumber,
mtrefstat.NAME                            AS meterStatus,
mt.ADDRESS                                AS address,
mt.SERIAL_NUMBER                          AS serialNumber,
mt.UPPER_SERIAL_NUMBER                    AS upperSerialNumber,
servrefstat.NAME                          AS serverStatus,
mus.MAC                                   AS hostname,
mserv.IP_ADDRESS                          AS ipAddress ,
mt.device_id                              AS deviceID,
GET_ACCESSCONNECTION_TYPE(mus.device_id)  AS ACCESSCONNECTIONTYPE,
FUNC_LIST_OBIS_NAME(ro.order_read_out_id) AS refObisList,
mt.METER_NUMBER                           AS meterNumber
FROM ORDER_READ_OUT ro,
REF_METER_READ_OUT_TYPE rot,
COMPANY cp,
METER_POINT mp,
METER mt,
MAP_DEVICE_STATUS mtstat,
REF_STATUS mtrefstat,
DEVICE servdev,
MUS mus,
METERING_SERVER mserv,
MAP_DEVICE_STATUS servstat,
REF_STATUS servrefstat,
MAP_ORD_RD_OUT_CNTRCT_MT_PT mocm,
MAP_CONTRACT_METER_POINT mcm,
CONTRACT co
WHERE -- order readout relation has to be valid
mocm .ORDER_READ_OUT_ID         = ro.ORDER_READ_OUT_ID
AND ro.REF_METER_READ_OUT_TYPE_ID = rot.REF_METER_READ_OUT_TYPE_ID
AND ro.ACTIVATION_DATE           <= SYSTIMESTAMP
AND (ro.DEACTIVATION_DATE        IS NULL
OR ro.DEACTIVATION_DATE           > SYSTIMESTAMP)
-- contract relation has to be valid ...
AND mocm.MAP_CONTRACT_METER_POINT_ID = mcm.MAP_CONTRACT_METER_POINT_ID
AND mcm.CONTRACT_ID                  = co.CONTRACT_ID
AND co.COMPANY_ID                    = cp.COMPANY_ID
AND ((co.BEGIN                      IS NULL
AND mcm.BEGIN                       <= SYSTIMESTAMP)
OR (co.BEGIN                        <= SYSTIMESTAMP
AND mcm.BEGIN                       <= SYSTIMESTAMP
AND mcm.begin                       >= co.begin))
AND (mcm.end                        IS NULL
OR mcm.end                          >= SYSTIMESTAMP)
AND ((co.END                        IS NULL)
OR (co.END                          >= SYSTIMESTAMP
AND ((mcm.end                       IS NULL)
OR (mcm.end                         <= co.end))))
-- meter point relation has to be valid ...
AND mcm.METER_POINT_ID   = mp.METER_POINT_ID
AND mp.METER_POINT_ID    = mt.METER_POINT_ID
AND mt.DEVICE_ID         = mtstat.DEVICE_ID
AND mtstat.REF_STATUS_ID = mtrefstat.REF_STATUS_ID
AND (mtrefstat.name      = 'active'
OR mtrefstat.name        = 'toBeRemoved')
AND mtstat.STATUS_DATE   =
(SELECT MAX(mds.status_date)
FROM Map_device_status mds
WHERE mds.device_id = mtstat.DEVICE_ID
)
-- mus/metering-server relation has to be valid
AND servdev.DEVICE_ID =
(SELECT FUNC_FIND_SERVER_DEV_ID(mt.DEVICE_ID) FROM DUAL
)
AND servdev.DEVICE_ID      = mus.DEVICE_ID(+)
AND servdev.DEVICE_ID      = mserv.DEVICE_ID(+)
AND servdev.DEVICE_ID      = servstat.DEVICE_ID
AND servstat.REF_STATUS_ID = servrefstat.REF_STATUS_ID
AND (servrefstat.name      = 'active'
OR servrefstat.name        = 'toBeRemoved')
AND servstat.STATUS_DATE   =
(SELECT MAX(mds.status_date)
FROM Map_device_status mds
WHERE mds.device_id = servstat.DEVICE_ID
)
AND ro.CREATION_DATE =
(SELECT MAX(t9.CREATION_DATE)
FROM ORDER_READ_OUT t9
WHERE t9.point_of_time_day        = ro.point_of_time_day
AND t9.point_of_time_hour         = ro.point_of_time_hour
AND t9.point_of_time_minute       = ro.point_of_time_minute
AND t9.ref_meter_read_out_type_id = ro.ref_meter_read_out_type_id
AND t9.ORDER_READ_OUT_ID         IN
(SELECT t5.ORDER_READ_OUT_ID
FROM map_ord_rd_out_cntrct_mt_pt t5
WHERE t5.MAP_CONTRACT_METER_POINT_ID = mcm.MAP_CONTRACT_METER_POINT_ID
));
```

Plans snippet:
`explain plan for SELECT count(1) FROM RULE_READOUT_VIEW WHERE READOUTTYPE = '5' AND CUSTOMERNUMBER = 'NSMPF';`

|  19 |                  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| REF_METER_READ_OUT_TYPE       |     1 |     7 |     1 |
|  20 |                   INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | UQ_REF_METER_READ_OUT_TY_NAME |     1 |       |     0

```
    explain plan for SELECT count(1) FROM RULE_READOUT_VIEW WHERE to_char(READOUTTYPE) = '5' AND CUSTOMERNUMBER = 'NSMPF';
```

|  14 |               INDEX FAST FULL SCAN          | PK_METERREADTYPE              |     1 |     7 |     1 |
|  15 |               INDEX FAST FULL SCAN          | UQ_REF_METER_READ_OUT_TY_NAME |     1 |     7 |     1 |

Comment: Make sure your readouttype column is clean, i.e. no entries with whitespace in them.

Comment: I checked the column values. i donot see any addtional white spaces before or after. Also if i run below query too i get 11 rows SELECT count(1) FROM RULE_READOUT_VIEW WHERE READOUTTYPE like '5' AND CUSTOMERNUMBER = 'NSMPF'. The problem seems to be only if i use the equality operator alone.

Comment: How did you check? Both your "working" queries indicate that your readout column doesn't contain only a '5' but also has some other whitespace-like stuff.

Comment: In order to check there are no white spaces i ran the below query: SELECT count(1) FROM RULE_READOUT_VIEW WHERE READOUTTYPE = 5 AND CUSTOMERNUMBER = 'NSMPF' where oracle should attempt implicit to_number conversion for column readoutype. This query returned 11 rows too. If there are whitespaces oracle should have thrown error during implicit type conversion. Am i correct?

Comment: No. Your `to_char` does the same thing, the implicit conversion will 'strip' whitespace. Replace the count with `length(readouttype)` or `utl_raw.cast_to_raw(readouttype)`.

Comment: Hi Mat, I ran lenght(readoutype) too. all of 11 rows returned only one as length. so there seems to be no issue with whitspaces.

Comment: Use Dump(readouttype) to see exactly what is stored in those columns

Comment: Count(1) is no different from Count(*), by the way.

Comment: Hi David, I ran dump on th readoutype column. All 11 rows are identical too with dump values as "Typ=1 Len=1: 53" for all rows.

Comment: Really strange. Is that really a view or a plain table? If view, can we see the definition? What's your Oracle version & patchset?

Comment: Hi Mat, it is actually a view. The view ddl is too big that i cannot edit and post it in my quesion.

Comment: Hi Mat, I managed to add view DDL to the question.

Comment: @Mat, My oracle version and patch version are `OPatch version    : 11.1.0.6.6 OUI version: 11.2.0.1.0`

Comment: Might be an Oracle bug which is hidden/triggered by a plan change. You could test this theory with hints

Comment: @WW., Which query hint are you suggesting to find the issue?

Comment: @thiyaga Well, you could obtain a plan for the two statements and see how they differ.  The to_char() might get in the way on an index, and cause Oracle to switch to a different plan.  Then, you could use hints to force Oracle into different plan to narrow down if this is the cause.  The hints are likely going to be very complicated due to the complexity of the view itself.

Answer (score 1):

Idea 1:

When you run this query, you should get the problematic rows back:-

```
SELECT READOUTTYPE, TO_CHAR(READOUTTYPE), LENGTH(READOUTTYPE) 
FROM RULE_READOUT_VIEW
WHERE to_char( READOUTTPYE ) = '5'
AND READOUTTYPE != '5'
AND CUSTOMERNUMBER = 'NSMPF';
```

Perhaps update your question with the result of this query to see if it makes it clear to anyone.

Idea 2:

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP_RULE_READOUT AS 
SELECT * FROM RULE_READOUT_VIEW
WHERE CUSTOMERNUMBER = 'NSMPF';

SELECT count(1) FROM TEMP_RULE_READOUT
WHERE READOUTTYPE = '5' AND CUSTOMERNUMBER = 'NSMPF';

SELECT count(1) FROM RULE_READOUT_VIEW
WHERE to_char(READOUTTYPE) = '5' AND CUSTOMERNUMBER = 'NSMPF';
```

It would be interesting to see is this works correctly or not when the data is materialised into a table.

Comment: I ran the query you asked. There are no rows returned by the below query SQL> SELECT READOUTTYPE, TO_CHAR(READOUTTYPE), LENGTH(READOUTTYPE), LENGTH(TO_CHAR(READOUTTYPE)) FROM teoss.RULE_READOUT_VIEW WHERE TO_CHAR(READOUTTYPE ) = '5' AND READOUTTYPE != '5' AND CUSTOMERNUMBER = 'NSMPF'; no rows selected

Comment: Your Idea2 seems to produce correct results. If i run the query on the temporary table that is created then i get correct result. However i still do not get how it is working on the table that is created from view but does not work on the view itself?

Comment: @thiyaga I think that the data itself is ok, and you are running into an Oracle bug of some description, which is triggered/hidden by the difference in plan caused by the different queries.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you might have a corrupt index on REF_METER_READ_OUT_TYPE.NAME, and the difference between the query results is explained by a difference in whether the index is used or not.

Try dropping and recreating the index (not rebuilding, as that might preserve any corruption).

Comment: I dropped and recreated the index. Still the same issue.

Comment: Can you post the execution plans for the two queries?

Comment: Since i cannot post complete plan as it exceeds allowed size i have updated my query with snippet of plan which uses the readoutype column.